# Converted Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I was writing a batch file and I tried this command %~f0.
Then notepad ++ ask me to reload the file because it was edited from another program.
I reloaded it and all the batch code became this strange black squares.
How can I get the code back? Please Help!!!

Comment: Sounds like something or the operator error modified the file.  Unless notepad ++ cant read it properly.  Try opening it in a hex editor and looking at the contents. There is a Notepad ++ plugin http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using %~f0 gives the full name and path of the batch file under execution. I don't think it can corrupt your file. Unless you rewrote on to that file by accident (redirection?). in that case your file is lost :(